# Youtube API 3.0 search videos and get video statistics at single request

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm searching youtube videos with youtube api 3.0.

I'm using this type of example API request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key=[API_KEY]
```

But i want to get statistics of videos with in the same api request. How to solve this problem.

Note: When I'm using `statistics` key with part. I got error.

I'm also tried this request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet,statistics&key=[API_KEY]
```

Comment: Why did you accept the answer that doesn't fit your question?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The resource `search.list` don't have the **part** `statistics`.

### Step 1 :

You need to get the `videoId` of the video: `"videoId": "UHdgXkkVyl0"` with `search.list`.

The request :

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&q=tuto&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

The response:

```
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"MmqJLb8ZBOWRQIsg7xej7lrKLMI/34CzOO9FXYQg7kdlOeoe59LsWVk\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "UHdgXkkVyl0"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"MmqJLb8ZBOWRQIsg7xej7lrKLMI/U303dB0TgZ89ODlqdwuKs5efOdk\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "LvEA2KHWQec"
   }
  },
```

### Step 2 :

After you have searched videos with `search.list` you need to make a second call to the API with the resource `video.list` with **parameters** :

```
part: statistics
id: "id of the video found in previous request"
```

- If you have more than one video `id` you can specify the id of videos with a comma-separated list like :

  id: "Xxsdw6zG1bg, Xxsdw6zG1bg,...." )

The request: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=UHdgXkkVyl0%2C+Xxsdw6zG1bg&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

The response will be like this :

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"MmqJLb8ZBOWRQIsg7xej7lrKLMI/rxvjZzq2nNqBg7Me5VQv1ToZm64\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 2,
  "resultsPerPage": 2
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"MmqJLb8ZBOWRQIsg7xej7lrKLMI/3fah-cngFxFOnytseMYZU1TK_-8\"",
   "id": "UHdgXkkVyl0",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "3070836",
    "likeCount": "72140",
    "dislikeCount": "1132",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "7798"
   }
  },
  {

   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"MmqJLb8ZBOWRQIsg7xej7lrKLMI/J4xM7Dd23TGYU6on-PESyEIAE9A\"",
   "id": "Xxsdw6zG1bg",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "131487",
    "likeCount": "1459",
    "dislikeCount": "25",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "39"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

And you have the statistics !

Comment: Why do they now require you to make two separate requests for this?

Comment: @MattO'Connell because you want search AND get statistics = 1 + 1 = 2

Comment: @mpgn, 1 + 2 = 2? Very helpful. I'm asking why they would force two separate requests with the 3.0 API vs a the single request that was needed in earlier versions to retrieve the same data

Comment: The STATISTICS part stopped working for me today. What happened?!?!

Comment: @pdolinaj It seems (just checked now) if the video doesn't allow to share video stats you can't get it by youtube-api. :( [**monosnap-screenshot**](http://take.ms/fDPSE)

Comment: @Wizard The stats are back so looks like it was a glitch with the YouTube API.

Comment: the '?' before the query params is missing in the second request

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, dislikeCount attribute has became private, in december 2021. according the youtube api docs.